# All localnotifications sent on bootup

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

In my app I set several local notifications.
Then I force-restart the device and when it boots back up every notification fires even if the time isn't up. Is this an iOS 4 bug or am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: Please post your code in which you set up the notifications.

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can better understand your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was user error! Somebody had set that device's date to something ridiculous and I failed to notice. Relentless QA testers ftw.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the system fires the notifications if the time is not up yet. You may have set the notification on wrong dates, or there may be a *timezone* issue. Make sure the *fireDate* is correct. That should be the only problem.